# Google Drive: algorithm to compute breadcrumb for a FS where nodes have multiple parents

Tags: javascript, java, algorithm, scala, google-drive-api

I'm currently working with Google Drive API and I need to display a breadcrumb of a Google Drive file in my app. Google Drive is not a simple tree and has a particularity that a file/folder may have multiple parents. Google Drive does not have the concept of breadcrumb, so the only way to get a breadcrumb (actually a list of potential breadcrumbs) is to recurse over the list of parents.

I'm currently able to compute a list of all potential breadcrumbs in Scala:

```
type GoogleDriveBreadcrumb = List[GoogleDriveFile]

def getAllBreadcrumbs(fileId: String): Try[List[GoogleDriveBreadcrumb]] = Try {

  def getBreadcrumbsRecursive(currentFileId: String): List[GoogleDriveBreadcrumb] = {
    val file = fetchDriveFile(currentFileId)
    file.parentIds.flatMap { parentId =>
      getBreadcrumbsRecursive(parentId)
        .map(parentBreadcrumb => file :: parentBreadcrumb)
    }
  }

  getBreadcrumbsRecursive(fileId)
}
```

This works fine but can be quite expensive and not really usable because:

- I don't actually need all the breadcrumbs, I need the most appropriate one because I know in which "context" to compute the breadcrumb. I'd like to be able to provide a `rootFolderId` parameter to this method, so that it will only return a single breadcrumb (the one having `rootFolderId` as parent, and this breadcrumb will be truncated at the level of the `rootFolderId` which means the returned breadcrumb should not include parents of `rootFolderId`. If `rootFolderId` is not found in any breadcrumb, the method can return the current file only
- It will always compute all the breadcrumbs in all cases. I'd like the computation to be lazy and to stop as soon as a breadcrumb containing `rootFolderId` is found.

---

I'd like my method to have this signature:

```
def getBreadcrumb(fileId: String,rootFolderId: String): Try[Option[GoogleDriveBreadcrumb]]
```

Now let's imagine I have a this Drive filesystem where `File` has 3 potential breadcrumbs:

```
File < Folder1 < Folder2 < Folder3
File < Folder4 < Folder5 < Folder6
File < Folder7 < Folder8 < Folder9
```

- `getBreadcrumb(file,folder5Id)` should return `File < Folder4 < Folder5`
- `getBreadcrumb(file,folder7Id)` should return `File < Folder7`
- `getBreadcrumb(file,badFolderId)` should return `File`

Any idea on how to rework my algorithm to achieve this goal, so that the algorithm is also efficient (stop as soon as the correct breadcrumb is found)

Thanks

---

I'm tagging this question with Scala,Java,Javascript because these are languages I am used to. I'd rather like a Scala-based implementation but I'm open for other languages as long as I can understand the solution.

Answer (score 0):

You could try starting from the file then going to the root folder.

If you are using v2, you'll repeat the loop until `isRoot` becomes true:

File result:

```
 "parents": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#parentReference",
   "id": "FILEID",
   ........................
   "isRoot": false
  }
 ]
```

Root result:

```
 "parents": [
  {
   "kind": "drive#parentReference",
   "id": "FILEID",
   ........................
   "isRoot": true
  }
 ]
```

If you are using v3:

If you are using v3, you'll repeat the query loop until `parents` becomes **`null`** or the response does not contain parents object.

File result:

```
{
 "id": "FILEID",
 "parents": [
  "PARENTID"
 ]
}
```

Root Result:

```
{
 "id": "ROOTID"
}
```

You can also check this [Google Apps Script tutorial](https://www.labnol.org/internet/google-drive-tree/21198/?_ga=1.98325023.1034291287.1477932151) on how listing it as a file tree (but in your case just the path from file to root)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about Apps Scripts I'll take a look at that. I'm using V3 and I am already able to list all potential breadcrumbs of a file by recursing over the parents field: it does not seem what you propose goes further of what I've already done so far